# How to set vi mode _while_ already typing the command?

Tags: bash, vi

I know I can set bash in vi mode giving `set -o vi` in the command line. However I find I need vi mode only sometimes and I would like to keep using the normal mode (emacs mode?) and would be lovely to be able to switch to vi mode while I am already typing my new command.

Is there any way to set the vi mode without issuing a CLI command?

For instance it could be switched on by the Terminal application. I use iTerm2 on Mac OS X but I could not find a command to switch mode on the fly.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to bind the two Readline functions `vi-insertion-mode` and `emacs-editing-mode` to a control key combination to toggle between these two input modes on the fly.

The code below first binds `vi-insertion-mode` to <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> in `emacs-standard` mode, and then binds `emacs-editing-mode` to <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> (the same key combination, but) in `vi-insert` mode.

```bsh
bind -m emacs-standard '"\C-x\C-t": vi-insertion-mode'
bind -m vi-insert      '"\C-x\C-t": emacs-editing-mode'
```

You may use any control sequence that does not interfere with too many other things and that makes sense to you.  The sequence used here is unbound by default.